# How to bind labelfor text to dropdown in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to fetch the text in labelfor variable by passing only few values because i need to bind only those which are checked but below one was returning empty I am getting the checked values into checked selectedvalues variable i need to bind only those values to labelfor how can i do this.

```
var checkedvalues= "8957,82234"  //values
   $("label[for='ddl1']:checked").text();
var text= $( "label[for='" + checkedvalues + "']" ).attr( "for", ddl1 );
```

I had tried the above two but they are not working

Answer (score 1):

Because your selector selects literal text inside `for` that must be `for="8957,82234"`. If you want to select 2 elements by `for` attribute, you must do

```
$("label[for='8957'], label[for='82234']")
```

---

```
var text = $().attr("for", ddl1);
```

is empty because `.attr(attribute, value)` is setter and does not return anything. `var = text = $().attr('for')` would return attribute values

---

```
$("label[for='ddl1']:checked")
```

Label does not have pseudo selector [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

> The `:checked` selector works for checkboxes, radio buttons, and options of select elements.

Maybe you want something like `$('#ddl1:checked').closest('label')`?

---

```
checkedvalues= "8957,82234"  //values
```

you can't set `label` to be bind by values, only by ID

Comment: the Labelfor is in  <li> <input> <labelfor>Checked1</labelfor> </li>  can you please suggest thats not working

Comment: how should i pass checkedvalues= "8957,82234" to  var text = $().attr("for", ddl1);

Comment: @testusernewn 1. `<labelfor>` is not same as `<label for="">`. 2. What exactly you want to do with `checkedValues`? Set it as attribute value or select DOM element by it? `.attr("for", ddl1)` will set attribute `for` to value of `ddl1` variable